# Docker Windows Container 403 - Forbidden: Access is Denied

Tags: asp.net, windows-10, sql-server-express, nancy, docker-desktop

I have created an image using the following script in my `Dockerfile`, but when I browse using the container's IP Address and port(2000), I get a 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. I am using Windows 10.0.14393 Build 14393, **Docker Desktop for Windows**. The project is an ASP.NET solution containing Nancy, Entity Framework, AngularJS, and SQL Server projects. Do I need to make any configuration changes to my IIS, Docker, Powershell, etc.? My Dockerfile script is:

```dockerfile
FROM microsoft/aspnet:windowsservercore
# using powershell commands
SHELL ["powershell"]

# location of the source directory
WORKDIR C:/src/Project


# run project using port 2000
RUN Remove-Website -Name 'Default Web Site'; \
    New-Website -Name 'Project' -Port 2000 -PhysicalPath 'C:/src/Project'
```

Comment: I am also getting the same error

Comment: hey did you find any solution?

Comment: I’m having the same problem with no solution

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure that your files not ignore in .dockerignore
2. copy this Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY . /inetpub/wwwroot
# Give Full Access To Folder
RUN icacls 'c:/inetpub/wwwroot' /grant 'Everyone:(OI)(CI)F'
# Check that the files have been successfully copied
RUN dir
```

3. docker build -t test .
4. docker run -p 8001:80 test

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately it can be many things...
I had the same issue and the problem was that the `/inetpub/wwwroot` folder was empty.
I can see that you are adding a new website folder instead, but you can try:

My docker file is

```
# FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.1-windowsservercore-1709
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.1-windowsservercore-ltsc2016
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} /inetpub/wwwroot
```

You can also try the solutions proposed in here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/iis-docker/issues/5

Cheers!

EDIT:
I also had issues when using localhost or 127.0.0.1. Use the public IP address